# Github showing commits with other collaborators knowing the fact that I haven't changed those files

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

The PR Page of the repo
[image: The PR Page of the repo]

I have had only one commit and that is the fourth one in that list but there are extra three commits with collaborations from other developers which I havent taken part in. What is the main reason behind this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Make your repository private and don't give them the password.

Comment: And dont use tags that have nothing to do with the question. This is **not** a java related question.

Comment: Thanks for the replies ! Sorry for the irrelevant java tag!